# Windows 7 Is There A Way To Limit A Specific Browser To Localhost Only With No Internet Access?

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet, browser, localhost

I want to lock down a browser I use for development specifically for localhost use only and not allow it access to the internet at all.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can add an invalid proxy to use and have it exempt localhost.

Comment: I tried that as mentioned in reply to the answer below. No idea why it didn't work for me. Thanks for your tip anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a proxy server address of 127.0.0.1 and then check the box to bypass the proxy for local addresses.  All borwsers support this.  When you try to visit a site, the browser will attempt to contact the proxy server and fail.  The bypass checkbox still allows it to get to local addresses and anything on your local intranet, however.

If you want to enforce this as an option the user can't change, you'd need to do that through Group Policy, but that only applies to Internet Explorer.  For Chrome and Firefox you're out of luck in that department.

Comment: I really like your thinking on this and tried to use this in Pale Moon which is a FF derived browser. Going into Options > Advanced > Network I entered 127.0.0.1 as the proxy server address and specified localhost ,127.0.0.1 as the bypass. Curiously after defining all that and rebooting the browser I can still get online. Scratching head on this still.

Comment: Hmm.  I just tried it in FF and it worked.  Try setting the port number to something like 8080 or a port you know is closed on your firewall and try it.  Also make sure it's set for all protocols.

Comment: Ok... Great! that worked although my localhost setup is also set to virtualhosts so my virtualhost sites didn't work till I added each one manually to the excluded list as well. Thanks so much : )